# Question on "Out of"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, compounds

In "out of", is the "out" considered a preposition or an adverb?

Comment: It gets worse: "Get **on up out of** here" is a colloquial (Southern American) preposition cluster that is used for emphasis (i.e., when one preposition simply isn't enough).

Answer (score 1):

*Out of* is a two word [preposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions).

In other words, both words together form the preposition.

Comment: And the second word is often deleted. _He ran out the door_ and _He ran out of the door_ are identical and equally grammatical.